# is the member variables name defined in the Angular and Spring boot entity class should match?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, variables, entity

is member variables names defined in the angular web page should match with member variables created in entity class in spring boot rest controller.

Angular:

```
export class Todo {
 constructor(
  public id: number,
  public userName: String,
  public task: string,
  public isDone: boolean,
  public completionDate: Date)}

@Entity
 public class ToDo {
  @Id
  private long id;
  private String userName;
  private String description;
  private Date targetDate;
  private boolean isCompleted;}
```

I have done the getter setter in spring boot. If I call the service from the angular, I can see the  response printed out in logs,. but not displayed in the web page.

If I keep the names same then its working fine. is it mandatory to keep the names same?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your question is if the model of the Angular Frontend needs to have **matching** names of the variables of those in the model of the Spring Backend.

**Frontend**:

```
export class Todo {
 constructor(
  public id: number,
 ...
```

**Backend**:

```
public class ToDo {
  @Id
  private long id;
...
```

here the 'id' has the **same name**, in the Frontend, just like the Backend.

From my Experience: **Yes. It has to be named the same**, im not quite sure why tho. Maybe the access to the database has some issues, when the naming is not identical.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

Yes, it seems that variable name must match.
When i tried different variable name then value in database shows 0 for mobilno.

Angular:

```
    export class User{
       username:string;
       password:string;
       mobileno:number;

       constructor(username:string , password:string, mobileno:number){
          this.username=username;
          this.password=password;
          this.mobileno=mobileno;
       }
   }
```

SpringBoot:

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    @Entity
    public class User_Entity {
        @Id
        public String username;
        public String password;
        public long mobileno;
    }
```